# How to add multiple Leaflet map on the same page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I want to add multiple Leaflet map with different content on the same page but it gives me the error:

```
Map container is already initialized.
```

I'm initializing the map in a `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) {
      const newMap = L.map("map", {
        zoomControl: true,
        minZoom: minZoom,
        maxZoom: maxZoom,
        maxBounds: latLngBounds,
        attributionControl: false,
      }).setView(latLngCenter, defaultZoom)

      L.tileLayer("https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png").addTo(
        newMap
      )
      setMap(newMap)
    }
  }, [map])
```

Then I'm returning a div with `id=map`.

I'm getting the error on line `const newMap`. I think we can't have 2 maps on the same page with different contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think we can't have 2 maps on the same page with different contents?

You *can*, but make sure you use 2 different containers. And an [HTML `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) should be used only once, because when querying by id, only the first one is found.

Hence the error message if you get another map container with the same `id`.

The usual workaround is to pass to the [`L.map()` factory](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-l-map) not the container `id` value, but the container itself (as an HTMLElement).

With React, you would use the [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for this purpose. That way, your React custom Component would initialize only its own map container, and you can instantiate as many Components with map as you wish:

```
function CustomMapComponent() {
  const mapContainerRef = useRef(null)
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapContainerRef.current) {
      const newMap = L.map(mapContainerRef.current, options)
      setMap(newMap)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div ref={mapContainerRef} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged that you use reactjs. I would recommend to use leaflet-react
https://react-leaflet.js.org/
Then you can use as many maps you want since you use the maps as normal components.